# Google Map errors/warnings appear when scrolling around in the map

Tags: android, google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a Google Maps implemented in my Ionic2 project. After building and testing on an Android device, I started scrolling through the map when I was hit with these warnings/errors:

[image]

[image]

Is there anything I can do to find the root of these issues or fix these warnings? Thanks.